# Aligning cases conditions from multiple nesting levels

Tags: vertical-alignment, cases

```
\begin{dmath*}
y_{ic}[n] = \begin{dcases}
                          y_0 + x_0 - x_0 (1 - k_2)^n & k_1 = 0 \\
                          k_5 + \left( y_0 - k_5 \right) (1 - k_1)^n + \begin{dcases}
                                             x_0 k_1 n (1 - k_1)^{n-1} & k_1 \neq 0, k_1 = k_2 \\
                                             x_0 \frac{k_2}{k_1 - k_2} \left[ \begin{split}&(1 - k_2)^n \\ & - (1 - k_1)^n \end{split} \right] & k_1 \neq 0, k_1 \neq k_2
                                                                                             \end{dcases}
                  \end{dcases}
\end{dmath*}
```

[image]

Is there any way I can get the conditions, which come from multiple `dcases` nesting levels, to appear in a single vertical column? (This would not only look nicer but save a lot of horizontal space, allowing the LHS of the entire equation to fit on the same line instead of wrapping.)

---

Followup: The solution provided by Harish worked very nicely... and then I noticed that I didn't need a separate case for $k_1 = 0$ (The analysis was different but led to the same result as the others -- I guess that's fairly common with partial fraction expansions).

[image]

Comment: I believe it would be clearer with a single three item `cases` environment.

Comment: Related: [How to align nested cases?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84035/5764)

Comment: @Werner: I already found and tried to apply that approach... but it didn't work correctly since my third row is taller than the minimum.

Comment: IMHO using Iversonians or Characteristic Functions instead of case-based definitions would make this expression clearer.

Comment: @BenVoigt -- yes, i did, but obviously not carefully enough.  you have undone the intended correction, which was to double the backslash intended to separate the lines in `dcases`,  a problem which was caused by a system update affecting well over 7000 items.  (please look at the meta explanation of the mess.  we've been left by the system managers to fix it on our own; we're trying desperately to do that before we get more questions about code that doesn't work.)  i apologize for the mess, but ask you to please make that necessary correction.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Sounds like a gargantuan mess.  Thanks for your hard work, I think I've made the necessary correction here.  (I think your edit just had one accidental extra `d` typed in but it broke formatting for the rest of the block)

Comment: @BenVoigt -- the double backslashes look good.  thanks for cleaning up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I were to do this, I would have listened to egreg's comments above. But the following works though coding may be ugly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,breqn}
\begin{document}
  \begin{dmath*}
y_{ic}[n] = \begin{dcases}
                          y_0 + x_0 - x_0 (1 - k_2)^n & k_1 = 0 \\
                          k_5 + \left( y_0 - k_5 \right) (1 - k_1)^n + \begin{dcases}
                                             x_0 k_1 n (1 - k_1)^{n-1}  &  \makebox[-11pt][l]{$k_1 \neq 0, k_1 = k_2$}\\
                                             x_0 \frac{k_2}{k_1 - k_2} \left[ \begin{aligned}(1 - k_2)^n \\  - (1 - k_1)^n \end{aligned} \right] & \makebox[-11pt][l]{$k_1 \neq 0, k_1 \neq k_2$}   
                                             \end{dcases}                                         
                  \end{dcases}
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I think I would do it in the way that egreg hinted at, and just use *one* `dcases` envrionment

[image: screenshot]

Note that I have replaced your `split` environment with an `array` and used `@{}c@{}` to remove column space (check your original `.log` file- you should have got a warning that you weren't allowed to use `split` in that context).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
y_{ic}[n] = 
    \begin{dcases}
          y_0 + x_0 - x_0 (1 - k_2)^n & k_1 = 0 \\
          k_5 + \left( y_0 - k_5 \right) (1 - k_1)^n + x_0 k_1 n (1 - k_1)^{n-1} & k_1 \neq 0, k_1 = k_2 \\
          k_5 + \left( y_0 - k_5 \right) (1 - k_1)^n+ x_0 \frac{k_2}{k_1 - k_2} \left[ \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}(1 - k_2)^n \\ - (1 - k_1)^n \end{array} \right] & k_1 \neq 0, k_1 \neq k_2
    \end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some more options that you could explore. Note that `cases` and friends can be easily emulated using an ordinary `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \setbox1=\hbox{$k_1 \neq 0, k_1 = k_2$}
  y_{ic}[n] = \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{\quad}l}
    y_0 + x_0 - x_0 (1 - k_2)^n, & \hspace*{\dimexpr-1em-\wd1-\nulldelimiterspace}k_1 = 0 \\[2\jot]
    k_5 + (y_0 - k_5) (1 - k_1)^n + \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}
      x_0 k_1 n (1 - k_1)^{n-1}, & k_1 \neq 0, k_1 = k_2 \\[\jot]
      \frac{x_0 k_2}{k_1 - k_2} [(1 - k_2)^n - (1 - k_1)^n], & k_1 \neq 0, k_1 \neq k_2
    \end{array}\right.
  \end{array}\right.
\]

\bigskip

\[
  \setbox1=\hbox{$k_1 \neq 0, k_1 = k_2$}
  y_{ic}[n] = \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{\quad}l}
    y_0 + x_0 - x_0 (1 - k_2)^n, & \hspace*{\dimexpr-1em-\wd1-\nulldelimiterspace}k_1 = 0 \\[2\jot]
    k_5 + (y_0 - k_5) (1 - k_1)^n \\ \qquad {} + \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}
      x_0 k_1 n (1 - k_1)^{n-1}, & k_1 \neq 0, k_1 = k_2 \\[\jot]
      \frac{x_0 k_2}{k_1 - k_2} [(1 - k_2)^n - (1 - k_1)^n ], & k_1 \neq 0, k_1 \neq k_2
    \end{array}\right.
  \end{array}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

The space-correction in the first row consists of 3 parts:

1. An `em` skip, stemming from the forced `@{\quad}` in the separation between the two columns;
2. `\wd1` (or the width of `\box1`) equal to the width of the condition(s) in row 2 and 3;
3. `\nulldelimiterspace`, since using `\right.` actually inserts a small gap.

Comment: What you've done is make both rows in the subordinate case block the same height... an inline fraction makes that possible but ugly.    I'd already tried this with a display-mode fraction, but the braces and conditions didn't line up then.  Thanks for the ideas though.