# Equation: How to create nested/multiple cases in LaTeX to align the qualifiers

Tags: equations, amsmath, align, cases

I am having trouble with a particular equation as the cases are nested within a case. 
It would also be cool if I could align the qualifiers.

I tried to post an image of the equation but I could not because I do not have a reputation score of 10. I have attached a link to the paper below ... equation 28 is the one I am having trouble with from this http://csr.sdsu.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Waves-as-a-Common-Pool-Resource.pdf:

[image]

Here is an example of what I have been using. I have tried a few variants {`\text{}` instead of `\mbox{}`, `\dcases` instead of `\cases`, etc.)

```
\begin{equation}
S_{i,t}=\begin{cases}
\begin{cases}
[x_{i,t}=X^*, r_{i,t}=1] & \mbox{if } \max\{X_{i,t}\}=X^* \\
[x_{i,t}=\max\{X_{i,t}\}, r_{i,t}=0] & \mbox{if } \max\{X_{i,t}\} \neq X^*
\end{cases} \text{if } \sum_{i=1}^I u_{i,t-1}= \theta^{t-2} X^*
\begin{cases} 
[x_{i,t}= 1, r_{i,t}=1] & text{if } \min \{X_{i,t}\}=1 \\
[x_{i,t} = \min \{X_{i,t}\}, r_{i,t}=0] & \text{if } \min \{X_{i,t}\} \neq 1
\end{cases} otherwise
\end{equation}
```

I have tried several different ways but I always get an error message ...

```
"overfull \hbox (14.0154pt too wide) in alignment at line ..."
```

Any advice would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. That is just a warning, not an error, and it means that something sticks a little bit into the right margin. Would be nice if you added the code of what you've attempted (a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)).

Comment: Nested alignment of cases is covered in [How to align nested `cases`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84035/5764)

Comment: not any answer, but it's more accepted practice to have "if" and "otherwise" as ordinary (usually roman) text; since you're using `amsmath`, you can just designate them as `\text{...}`.  even better if you use `\text{if $...$} for the whole condition.  also, `\max` to match `\min`.

Answer (score 13):

If you want a result really good-looking, adopt this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\maxmin}
\setlength{\maxmin}{\widthof{$\max$}-\widthof{$\min$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  S_{i,t}=
  \begin{cases}
    \begin{cases}
      [x_{i,t}=X^*, r_{i,t}=1] & \text{if  $\max\{X_{i,t}\}=X^*$} \\
      [x_{i,t}=\max\{X_{i,t}\}, r_{i,t}=0] & \text{if $\max\{X_{i,t}\} \neq X^*$}
    \end{cases}
    &\text{if $\sum_{i=1}^I u_{i,t-1}= \theta^{t-2} X^*$}\\
    \begin{cases}
      [x_{i,t}=1, r_{i,t}=1] & \hspace{\maxmin} \text{if $\min\{X_{i,t}\}=1$} \\
      [x_{i,t}=\min\{X_{i,t}\}, r_{i,t}=0] & \hspace{\maxmin} \text{if $\min\{X_{i,t}\} \neq 1$}
    \end{cases}
    &\text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can notice the perfect alignment of `if`s. This has been obtained (thanks to the package `calc`) calculating the difference of spacing between `\max` and `\min` and adding the corresponding difference in the second `cases` environment.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are just missing the `\\`and `&` of the outer `case`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
S_{i,t}=
\begin{cases}
  \begin{cases}
  [x_{i,t}=X^*, r_{i,t}=1] & \text{if  $\max\{X_{i,t}\}=X^*$} \\
  [x_{i,t}=\max\{X_{i,t}\}, r_{i,t}=0] & \text{if $\max\{X_{i,t}\} \neq X^*$}
  \end{cases} &\text{if $\sum_{i=1}^I u_{i,t-1}= \theta^{t-2} X^*$}\\
  \begin{cases} 
  [x_{i,t}= 1, r_{i,t}=1] & \text{if $\min \{X_{i,t}\}=1$} \\
  [x_{i,t} = \min \{X_{i,t}\}, r_{i,t}=0] & \text{if $ \min \{X_{i,t}\} \neq 1$}
  \end{cases} &\text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```