# How to align the conditions in a hierarchical structure?

Tags: vertical-alignment, conditionals

I know how to align the conditions on the left side of the conditions with either aligned, cases, or array if there is only one level. However, I can't figure out how to do so in a hierarchical structure of conditions with more than one level. For example, the following Latex code would only align all the conditions on the right side:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\text{Start} 
\left\{\begin{aligned} \text{Do A,} \quad \quad\quad \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{if a happens} \\
\text{otherwise} \left\{\begin{aligned} \text{Try B,}
    \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad\quad\quad \text{if b occurs}\\
\text{Try C} \left\{\begin{aligned} \text{Perform C1}  \quad \quad \text{if
      c increases}\\
\text{Perform C2, } \quad \text{if c decreases}
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

So the question is, how to align all the "if" conditions?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you seen [How to align nested cases?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84035) and [Equation: How to create nested/multiple cases in LaTeX to align the qualifiers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128070)

Comment: If it's code, then math mode may not be the best choice.

Comment: @morbusg: Thanks a lot for the suggestions! Those examples are similar to my situation, so I'll try them out. I tried to search "hierarchical conditions", but should have gone with "nested conditions". Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Thorsten Donig: Thanks for editing my post. I'm not so sure how to format the code. Also, how to embed an output of Latex code?

Comment: @bluepole: Have a look at the [help section for formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). Regarding code you can mark it and use the `{}` button right above the input window when composing a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the interline spacing by resetting the length `\LSG`, currently set to `1.4\baselineskip`.  The rest just stacking, and scaling the braces to the stack height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}[2013-10-15]
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\rbsa[2]{\raisebox{#1}{\scaleleftright[2ex]{\{}{#2}{.}}}
\def\stacktype{L}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\newlength{\LSG}
\setlength{\LSG}{1.4\baselineskip}
\setstackgap{L}{\LSG}
\begin{document}
\savestack{\cstack}{\rbsa{.5\LSG}{\stackunder{Perform C1}{Perform C2,}}}
\savestack{\bcstack}{\rbsa{\LSG}{\stackunder[1.5\LSG]{Try B,}{Try C\cstack}}}
\savestack{\abcstack}{\rbsa{1.5\LSG}{\stackunder[2\LSG]{Do A}{otherwise\bcstack}}}
Start\abcstack~~~~~~\Centerstack[l]
{if a happens\\if b occurs\\if c increases\\if c decreases}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get the alternate format, referenced by the OP:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}[2013-10-15]
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\rbsa[2]{\raisebox{#1}{\scaleleftright[2ex]{\{}{#2}{.}}}
\def\stacktype{L}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\newlength{\LSG}
\setlength{\LSG}{1.4\baselineskip}
\setstackgap{L}{\LSG}
\begin{document}
\savestack{\cstack}{\rbsa{.5\LSG}{\stackunder{Perform C1}{Perform C2,}}}
\savestack{\bcstack}{\rbsa{0.5\LSG}{\stackunder[1.5\LSG]{Try C\cstack}{Try B,}}}
\savestack{\abcstack}{\rbsa{1.5\LSG}{\stackunder[2\LSG]{Do A}{otherwise\bcstack}}}
Start\abcstack~~~~~~\Centerstack[l]
{if a happens\\if c increases\\if c decreases\\if b occurs}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that uses the `multirow` package and its eponymous command `\multirow`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,multirow}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Original code:
\begin{equation*}
\text{Start} 
\left\{\begin{aligned} \text{Do A,} \quad \quad\quad \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{if a happens} \\
\text{otherwise} \left\{\begin{aligned} \text{Try B,}
    \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad\quad\quad \text{if b occurs}\\
\text{Try C} \left\{\begin{aligned} \text{Perform C1}  \quad \quad \text{if
      c increases}\\
\text{Perform C2, } \quad \text{if c decreases}
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation*}

\bigskip\noindent
New code:
\begin{equation*}
\text{Start}
\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
   \text{Do A} & \text{if a happens}\\
   \multirow{3}{*}{$ % restart math mode
       \text{otherwise}  
       \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
         \text{Try B}\\
         \text{Try C} 
           \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
              \text{Perform C1}\\
              \text{Perform C2}
           \end{array} \right.
       \end{array} \right. %
   $} %  end of scope of multirow
   & \text{if b occurs   } \\
   & \text{if c increases} \\
   & \text{if c decreases} 
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Remark: This solution is similar in structure (and, in particular, the use of nested `array`s) to the one provided in [@Werner's answer to an earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84072/5001), except that the `multirow` package is used to here to typeset correctly the `otherwise` string (and the subsequent material)

---

*Addendum*: The OP has asked how one would exchange the order of the TryB/TryC items. To do so, exchange the order of the two rows in the middle of three `array` structures and (ii) rearrange the order of the "if b occurs"/"if c increases"/"if c decreases" strings.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\text{Start}
\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
   \text{Do A} & \text{if a happens}\\
   \multirow{3}{*}{$ % restart math mode
       \text{otherwise}  
       \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
         \text{Try C} 
           \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
              \text{Perform C1}\\
              \text{Perform C2}
           \end{array} \right. \\
         \text{Try B}
       \end{array} \right. %
   $} %  end of scope of multirow
   & \text{if c increases} \\
   & \text{if c decreases} \\
   & \text{if b occurs} 
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the kind help! Sorry, what difference does the typesetting of the `otherwise` string make? I fail to see the typeset difference between the two codes...

Comment: @bluepole - The main difference between the two sets of LaTeX code, output-wise, is that the four `if ...` statements are guaranteed to be vertically aligned with the new code. Similarly, the two `Perform C1`/`Perform C2` pair of statements are vertically aligned, as is the `Try B`/`Try C` pair. This is achieved through the use of (i) nested `align` environments and (ii) a `\multirow` statement that contains a complex three-row structure.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I also tried the suggestion from another thread referred to by @Werner, and it worked out equally well with the regular `array`.

Comment: @bluepole - just noticed a typo in my earlier comment -- the new code uses nested `array` environments, *not* nested `align` environments...

Comment: Thanks again! This is not a big deal, but is it possible to switch the two branches of `Try B` and `Try C`?

Answer (score 4):

I find the given structure a little difficult to follow: some of the if conditions are much to far from the actions they govern. Also, it seems that there ought to be another "otherwise" just before "Try C". I would reorganize the whole thing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\text{Start}
\ \begin{cases} \text{if a happens}& \text{Do A,} \\
                \text{otherwise}&
    \begin{cases}\text{if b occurs}& \text{Try B,}\\
                 \text{otherwise}& \text{Try C}
    \ \begin{cases}\text{if c increases}& \text{Perform C1,}\\
                   \text{if c decreases}& \text{Perform C2.}
      \end{cases}
    \end{cases}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I particularly like the suggestion to invert the ordering of conditions and actions. You can probably dispense with the `Try C` part, though, and go straight to the final `cases` environment.