# How to change the size of the brackets

Tags: brackets

```
\begin{document}

The algebraic system define over operator $\star$ , which is \emph{closed} and \emph{associative} is called SEMIGROUP.
The algebraic system define over operator $\star$ having property \emph{Closed}, \emph{Associative} and \emph{Identity} is  called MONOID.
\end{document}
```

I want to write 
1.closed 2.associative } semigroup
1.closed 2.associative 3.identity } monoid

I want to write 1.closed 2.associative in two different lines and  to combine them with long'}' symbol and to write semigroup .

How can I do that?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139954/how-to-align-the-conditions-in-a-hierarchical-structure/

Answer (score 2):

The following set of nested `array` environments may achieve what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{@{} ll @{}}
   \left.\begin{array}{@{} ll @{}}
      \left. \begin{array}{@{} ll @{}}
         \text{1. closed}\\
         \text{2. associative}
      \end{array}\right\} & \text{semigroup}\\
                          & \text{3. identity}
   \end{array}\right\} & \text{monoid}
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a drawing using TikZ package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width = 0.7pt]
  \def\h{0.45} % height
  \foreach \i/\txt in {1/closed, 2/associative, 3/identity} {
    \node at (0,-\i*\h) {\i. \txt};
  }
  \node[align = right] at (-2.3,-1.5*\h) {semigroup \Big\{};
  \node[align = left ] at ( 2.1,-2.0*\h) {\Bigg\} monoid};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]