# Aligning nested cases vertically

Tags: vertical-alignment, alignment, cases

I am trying to get something like the following: 
[image]

However, the code that I currently have makes the first brace too large vertically. It looks like this: 
[image]

Is there any way to amend this? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\text{Productive forces}\begin{cases}
\text{Means of production}
\begin{cases}
\text{Instruments of production}\\
\text{Raw materials} \\
\text{Spaces}
\end{cases} \\
\text{Labour power} 
\end{cases}                  
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139954/how-to-align-the-conditions-in-a-hierarchical-structure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\smash[t]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\text{Productive forces}\begin{cases}
\text{Means of production}
\smash[t]{\begin{cases}
\text{Instruments of production}\\
\text{Raw materials} \\
\text{Spaces}
\end{cases}} \\
\text{Labour power} 
\end{cases}                  
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of above code]

Comment: Did you  check whether the spacing w.r.t. the text above is preserved?

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, I know that the space with the text above is not preserved. But, if we want to preserve it, we have to use much more complicated techniques, such as the techniques described by Steven B. Segletes in his comment of the question. Maybe susypeti prefers to add the space by hand...

Comment: Yes, since combining this with custom spacing is simpler than the more complicated solutions, I went with the above answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You can `\smash` the second `cases` to hide its height and add a small length accordingly, say `2\normalbaselineskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\text{Productive forces}\begin{cases}
\text{Means of production}
\smash{\begin{cases}
\text{Instruments of production}\\
\text{Raw materials} \\
\text{Spaces}
\end{cases}} \\[2\normalbaselineskip]
\text{Labour power} 
\end{cases}                  
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You should consider that there might be possible surrounding text. The following puts the structure in a 4-row `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque metus magna, 
placerat laoreet feugiat a, fermentum id elit. Pellentesque sodales mauris eget 
condimentum ullamcorper. Phasellus sit amet tempus nunc.
\[
  % Vertical structure containing 4 rows of items
  \vphantom{\left\{\begin{tabular}{l}
    \strut \\ \strut \\ \strut \\ \strut
  \end{tabular}\right.}
  \smash{\begin{tabular}{l}
    \strut \\ \strut \\ % Two empty rows
    \strut \smash{Productive forces
      $\left\{
      \begin{tabular}{@{} l}
        \strut \smash{Means of production
        $\left\{\begin{tabular}{@{} l}
          Instruments of production \\
          Raw materials             \\
          Spaces
        \end{tabular}\right.$} \\ \\
        Labour power
      \end{tabular}
      \right.$} \\
    \strut % One empty row
  \end{tabular}}
\]
Sed consequat, mi sed vestibulum molestie, risus orci pulvinar libero, vitae 
consequat sapien nulla vel ipsum. Nulla porta tellus arcu, ac facilisis sapien 
rhoncus et.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution which does not have the inconvenience of having to adjust the spacing w.r.t. the surrounding text, based on `bigdelim`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[8]
\[
\begin{tabular}{l@{\,}c@{\,}l@{\,}c@{\,}l}
 & & &\ldelim\{{3}{*} & Instruments of production \\
  &\ldelim\{{3}{*} &Means of production & & Raw materials \\
Productive forces & & & & Spaces\\
 & & Labour power
\end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]